# Decreased Value for Clamp According to Ratio

Tags: html, css, clamp

I have a clamp with a min viewport of 430 and max viewport of 1920, I'm trying to figure out what my minimum value would be at 150px viewport according to this ratio
clamp(2rem, 11.678vw + -1.138rem, 12.875rem)

Answer (score 0):

If your clamp calculation is made for minimum viewport 430px then viewport 150px is less than that so it should result in `2rem`. I've looked at [the online calculator you mentioned in the comments](https://geary.co/clamp-calculator/). It assumes 1rem to be equal to 16px, so in fact your calculation is the same as:

```
clamp(32px, 11.678vw - 18.215px, 206px)
```

And so the resulting value for 150px viewport would be 32px (as expected as 2rem = 32px). And it is so - I've checked it by implementing it in the code and using devtools to inspect the value for proper viewport width.

Comment: I use this as my clamp calculator
https://geary.co/clamp-calculator/

Comment: @wondering, thanks, that clarified some things and I've updated my answer.